# cannot save a photo from PowerApps to SharePoint using the create file action

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

[image]

I have built a powerapps to take a picture from the app and save it to sharepoint. On the create file action I always get this error:

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_file' inputs at line '1' and column '2598': 'The template language expression 'dataUriToBinary(triggerBody()['CreatefileFileContent'])' cannot be evaluated because property 'CreatefileFileContent' doesn't exist, available properties are 'CreateitemTitle, SendanemailTo, Createfile_FileName, Updatefileproperties_ImageTypeValue'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, there is no property called "CreatefileFileContent" in the data that is coming from PowerApps. Few possibilities

- You meant Createfile_FileContent and forgot the underscore
- The data is not coming through PowerApps because whatever you are doing in PowerApps doesn't normally send that information and you are possibly out of luck
- The data is not coming through PowerApps because the PowerApps / PowerAutomate links are awful at the best of times and you are best served to delete the connector in PowerApps and recreate from scratch.